# Referencing embedded resource images in Windows .NET framework app

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-4.7.2

I want to deploy a Windows app running on .NET Framework v4.7.2 as a single file executable and embed images used as resources in the executable file. I don't want to migrate the app to .NET Core.

The image file is in the app as `Resources\Images\fred.png`; I have set the build action of the image file to `embedded resource` and `copy to output directory` to `do not copy`

[image: image properties]

I reference this in the code snippet:

```
var src = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/fred.png", UriKind.Absolute);
 return new BitmapImage(src);
```

`new BitmapImage(src)` generates a null exception because the file isn't found.

I have read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/aa970069(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and the uri path provided seems be correct.

I have also read some other SO posts but the either suggestions didn't work, or they weren't trying to embed an image file in an executable.

**My question is**: how can I load this image file as an embedded resource so I can deploy the application as a single-file executable?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the build action type from `embedded resource` to `resource` and that resolved the issue.